# list of dictionary of list of dictionary to a DataFrame with dynamic header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
data = [
    {
        "node_id"   : "1212",
        "name"      : "Adam",
        "country"   : "USA",
        "parent_ids": [
            {"parent_id": "123abc", "relation": "member"},
            {"parent_id": "124abc", "relation": "previous_member"},
        ],
    },
    {
        "node_id"   : "1213",
        "name"      : "Jane",
        "country"   : "USA",
        "parent_ids": [
            {"parent_id": "125abc", "relation": "member"},
        ],
    },
    {
        "node_id"   : "1214",
        "name"      : "Harry",
        "country"   : "UK",
        "parent_ids": [
            {"parent_id": "126abc", "relation": "member"},
            {"parent_id": "127abc", "relation": "previous_member"},
            {"parent_id": "128abc", "relation": "previous_member"},
        ],
    },
    {
        "node_id"   : "1215",
        "name"      : "Jimmy",
        "country"   : "USA",
        "parent_ids": [
            {"parent_id": "129abc", "relation": "member"},
            {"parent_id": "129abd", "relation": "previous_member"},
            {"parent_id": "129abe", "relation": "previous_member"},
            {"parent_id": "129abf", "relation": "member"},
        ],
    },
]
```

**desired dataframe**

| parent_id_1 | relation_1 | parent_id_2 | relation_2 | parent_id_3 | relation_3 | parent_id_4 | relation_4 | name | node_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123abc | member | 124abc | previous_member | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | Adam | 1212 |
| 125abc | previous_member | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | Jane | 1213 |
| 126abc | member | 127abc | previous_member | 128abc | previous_member | NaN | NaN | Harry | 1214 |
| 129abc | member | 129abd | previous_member | 129abe | previous_member | 129abf | previous_member | Jimmy | 1215 |

```
 I tried using 
pd.json_normalize(data) 
but all the parent_ids were in a list came inside parent_ids columns like
   

parent_ids  node_id name    country
[{'parent_id': '123abc', 'relation': 'member'}, {'parent_id': '124abc', 'relation': 'previous_member'}] 1212    Adam    USA
[{'parent_id': '125abc', 'relation': 'member'}] 1213    Jane    USA
[{'parent_id': '126abc', 'relation': 'member'}, {'parent_id': '127abc', 'relation': 'previous_member'}, {'parent_id': '128abc', 'relation': 'previous_member'}] 1214    Harry   UK
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? StackOverflow isn't a place to just come for answers, you should make an honest attempt at the problem and then narrow down your code to what you think is causing the problem. Please see [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There clearly is a data design issue. Or is it an exercise ?

Comment: @keepAlive don't know, probably an exercise. Got it on the first day of internship. I tried putting parent_ids into a separate list and then iterate though it to extract parent_id and relation but some have one parent_id and some have 3 or 4 so this is giving me problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            **d,
            **dict(sum(
                [
                    [
                        (f'{sub_k}_{i}', sub_v)
                        for sub_k, sub_v in sub_d.items()
                    ] for i, sub_d in enumerate(
                        d.pop('parent_ids'), start=1
                    )
                ],
                []
            ))
        } for d in data
    ]
)
```

which gives

```
  node_id   name country parent_id_1 relation_1 parent_id_2       relation_2  \
0    1212   Adam     USA      123abc     member      124abc  previous_member   
1    1213   Jane     USA      125abc     member         NaN              NaN   
2    1214  Harry      UK      126abc     member      127abc  previous_member   
3    1215  Jimmy     USA      129abc     member      129abd  previous_member   

  parent_id_3       relation_3 parent_id_4 relation_4  
0         NaN              NaN         NaN        NaN  
1         NaN              NaN         NaN        NaN  
2      128abc  previous_member         NaN        NaN  
3      129abe  previous_member      129abf     member
```

You can type `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)` to make `df` fit entirely within your screen.

Answer (score 1):

1. create dataframe using `json_normalize()`
2. expand the list `explode()`
3. turn embedded `dict` in list to columns `apply(pd.Series)`
4. reshape using `pivot()`
5. force back to flattened column names

```
# extract JSON...
df = pd.json_normalize(data).explode("parent_ids").reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(df.parent_ids.apply(pd.Series)).drop(columns="parent_ids")

# now reformat rows to columns
df = (df.assign(coln=(df.groupby(["node_id","name","country"]).cumcount()+1).astype(str))
 .pivot(index=["node_id","name","country"], columns=["coln"], values=["parent_id","relation"])
)

# don't want multiindex columns
df.columns = ["_".join(c) for c in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
```

### output

|  | node_id | name | country | parent_id_1 | parent_id_2 | parent_id_3 | parent_id_4 | relation_1 | relation_2 | relation_3 | relation_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1212 | Adam | USA | 123abc | 124abc | nan | nan | member | previous_member | nan | nan |
| 1 | 1213 | Jane | USA | 125abc | nan | nan | nan | member | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | 1214 | Harry | UK | 126abc | 127abc | 128abc | nan | member | previous_member | previous_member | nan |
| 3 | 1215 | Jimmy | USA | 129abc | 129abd | 129abe | 129abf | member | previous_member | previous_member | member |